# X-FRAME-OPTIONS set to deny but still opening iframes in clickjackers

Tags: node.js, content-security-policy, x-frame-options

I am trying to avoid clickjacking for the application. So, I set the x-frame-options header to deny but it is still opening iframes and any clickjack testing sites.

```
app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
console.log('Before processing - ', req.url, req.method);
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
res.header('Strict-Transport-Security', 'maxAge=100000');
res.header('X-Frame-Options', 'DENY');
res.header('Content-Security-Policy', "frame-ancestors 'none'");
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Cookies, cookies, x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type,    Accept');
return next();
});
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. How're you testing it?

Comment: I am testing on two different sites [http://web.clickjacker.io](http://web.clickjacker.io) and [https://www.lookout.net/test/clickjack.html](https://www.lookout.net/test/clickjack.html)

Comment: Did you inspect the request in the Network tab to see if the `X-Frame-Options: DENY` header is actually set in the response?

Comment: Yes, it is there in response headers, but [http://web.clickjacker.io](http://web.clickjacker.io) is showing as it is as Missing Header

Comment: Weird. Do the other clickjack testing sites report the same error?

Comment: Yeah, other sites are also not able to find the header.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your `X-Frame-Options` header using npm package `helmet`. Run `npm install helmet --save` in your app. And in your server file make these changes:

```
const express = require("express");
const helmet = require("helmet");

const app = express();

app.use(helmet());
```

Now to set `X-Frame-Options` as `DENY`, Add:

```
app.use(helmet.frameguard({ action: 'deny' }));
```

For more details, see https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/frameguard/. This setting denies all `<iframe>` content.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for interfere, but all works as intented, see https://repl.it/@egranty/Test-for-Anita.
After push green start button the NodeJS sanbox is started. Test page can be opened in a separate tab and be insetred into https://www.lookout.net/test/clickjack.html or https://clickjacker.io/test?url=https://test-for-anita--egranty.repl.co/.

Here is results in Chrome:
[image]

Note that if are published both `X-Frame-Options` and `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors` at the same time, the last one overrides the `X-Frame-Options` in the modern browsers [except Safari](https://csplite.com/csp76/#bug_Safari_frame-ancestors_X-Frame-Options).

That's why browser console shows lock in the `frame-ancestors 'none'`, but not in the `X-Frame-Options`.

So, you have a work NodeJS code, a work clickjacking test tools and as we can observe, `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` / `CSP frame-ancestors` definitely prohibits embedding pages.
May be some browser plugins interfere or it need to clear browser cache. But I think your nodeJS installation is broken and you need to reinstall it.

Comment: I figured out that I set the headers in my server but those clickjacking websites are calling get requests to the frontend and the frontend is not having that header. When I directly tried to call get the request URL of the server in an iframe, it stopped me from displaying the invalid token JSON. Now, I am figuring out how to set headers in a react app.

Comment: In serverless SPA there is only one way - delivery CSP with meta tag. You can use [react-static-plugin-csp-meta-tags](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-static-plugin-csp-meta-tags) plugin. Note, that frame-ancestors directive [is not supported](https://csplite.com/csp67/#restrictions) inside meta tag. Therefore you have to use additional meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="DENY">`.